# Configuring Iron Router in Meteor - React

Tags: meteor, reactjs, iron-router

Using Meteor 1.2.0.1 and React. My simple app works great but now I needed [iron router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router).

**app layout:**

```
client\
  app.jsx
lib\
  router.jsx
server
views\
  home.jsx
  layout.jsx
```

**home.jsx:**

```
Home = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
        <p>from home</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**layout.jsx:**

```
Layout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**routes.jsx:**

```
Router.route('/', () => {
  let page = (
    <Layout>
      <Home/>
    </Layout>
  );
  React.render(page, document.body);
});
```

Surely enough, in my `app.jsx`, works great as it displays to the body of the html but the setup would not work for a multi-page app so this is the need for routes. Inside is:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  let app = (
    <Layout>
      <Home/>
    </Layout>
  );
  React.render(app, document.body);
});
```

The question is, how to get iron router (`routes.jsx`) to show the contents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using [Flow Router](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router) instead of Iron Router. Add Flow Router to your app, then add [`kadira:react-layout`](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/react-layout) as well. Follow this format and it should work:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  action() {
    ReactLayout.render(Layout, {content: <Home />});
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/login', {
  name: 'loginPage',
  action() {
    ReactLayout.render(Layout, {content: <Login />});
  }
});
```

And your `Layout` component should look like:

```
Layout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />

        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

To route to a page that takes a parameter:

```
FlowRouter.route('/detail/:id', {
  name: 'prodDetail',
  action() {
    ReactLayout.render(Layout, {content: <ProdDetail />});
  }
});
```

And then in your `ProdDetail` component, you can refer to `FlowRouter.getParam('id')`. Check out the full [FlowRouter documentation](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I like the idea of rendering to an `id`. Is that possible?

Comment: On http://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/routing/ the path is meteor add meteorhacks:flow-router should i use meteorhacks or kadira?

Comment: Use `kadira:flow-router`. They moved it awhile ago.

Comment: Things will change, with Meteor 1.3: https://voice.kadira.io/getting-started-with-meteor-1-3-and-react-15e071e41cd1#.pr83g9bsy

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the [ejson package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ejson) which solved the issue, thanks to [Chris](https://twitter.com/cdmather). But I can easily follow Flow Router so I'll mark (since I'll be using it) that the answer but for anyone that has this issue, use the ejson package. However then my resolver over time.