# iron-meteor does not recognize react?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I successfully followed this guide to learn to use iron-meteor
https://medium.com/meteor-js/how-to-build-web-apps-ultra-fast-with-meteor-iron-scaffolding-and-automatic-form-generation-11734eda8e67#.gw50bxjif

So then I went to command line and did a `iron add react`.

I created a simple react component `app/client/templates/App.jsx` with the contents

```
App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        Hello World
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Then when in `app/lib/controllers/issues_list_controller.js` I replaced the action function with this code.

```
  action: function () {
//    this.render();

    var router = this;

    Meteor.startup(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<App router={router} />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
    });
  },
```

Now when I run the command `iron` from command line to start the project, I get the error

> W20151230-00:48:14.955(-5)? (STDERR)       ReactDOM.render(<App router={router} />, document.getElementById("render
>
> W20151230-00:48:14.957(-5)? (STDERR)                       ^
>
> W20151230-00:48:14.980(-5)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

It's as if meteor-iron doesn't recognize react and jsx mark up?  How do I get this to work?

Comment: as far as i know, iron router does not go well with react http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792092/configuring-iron-router-in-meteor-react I am on the way to move to `FlowRouter` as well

Comment: Thanks @ThaiTran, but I did a simple meteorjs + iron router + react app and that worked out fine.  Something about iron-meteor doesn't seem to recognize react mark up though...

Answer (score 0):

> Then when in `app/lib/controllers/issues_list_controller.js` I replaced the action function with this code.

`issues_list_controller.js` is a regular javascript file.  Rename it with the jsx extension if you want to use JSX in your code - i.e. `<App router={router} />` etc.